# Index Match for two criteria, then exclude previously returned values

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Using Google Sheets, I'm trying to figure out how to do an index match so I can find a value based on two crtieria...then as I continue to use the formula it will exclude all previously returned values.

Assuming 3 columns in all examples...

Sheet 1:

```
a  b  <blank>
a  b  <blank>
```

I'm trying to return values into the  column by looking for both a and b in another sheet...but I want only one new value to be returned each time.

Sheet 2:

```
a  b  c
a  b  d
a  b  e
```

So, for sheet one, I'd like the  to be:

```
a  b  c
a  b  d
```

I'm sure this is possible somehow, I just don't know how to make it happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A&B1:B&COUNTIFS(A1:A&B1:B, A1:A&B1:B, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A)), 
 {Sheet2!A1:A&Sheet2!B1:B&COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A1:A&Sheet2!B1:B, Sheet2!A1:A&Sheet2!B1:B, 
 ROW(Sheet2!A1:A), "<="&ROW(Sheet2!A1:A)), Sheet2!C1:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Whoa, this is great!! Could you break down the logic in words for me just so I can understand? Also is it possible to do this with 3 criteria?

Comment: sure. `COUNTIFS(A1:A&B1:B, A1:A&B1:B, ROW(A1:A), "<="&ROW(A1:A))` will count joined value of A&B so ever next same value gets next number then this is appended to A&B so the result is >> `ab1, ab2` same is done in other sheet so there the result is `ab1, ab2, ab3`. we append 3rd column from Sheet2 with this into VR array `{ }` and wrap all above into `VLOOKUP` (note that simple vlookup would never get to output value `d` in cell C2). and yes, its possible even with 3 criteria - logic is same

Comment: Thank you, now I'm just unclear on this part: "<="&ROW(A1:A) ... what exactly is this part doing?

Comment: that's the part that actually counts the occurrence against every next row and if the comparison is smaller or equal it will rise the counter by one. basically it counts the repetition of every unique value in a set